# If statement does not run even after user input

Tags: python, if-statement

```
optionone = 0    #DEFINING BOTH VARIABLES 
optiontwo = 0

class first_day_morning:    #WORKING 
    optionone = input("It is now morning, would you like to (1) Leave your house or (2) Do some chores? ")


def first_choice(optionone):        #NOT WORKING DOING ELSE COMMAND FOR 1 INPUT
     if optionone == 1: 
         time.sleep(1)
        print('')
        print("You have chosen to get out of the house for once")
    elif optionone == 2: 
        time.sleep(1)
        print('')
        print("DO LATER")
    else: 
        time.sleep(1)
        print('')
        print("please choose a valid option")

first_choice(int(input()))
```

I am trying to make it so that the user input decides the outcome of the if statement, if user inputs 1, then something happens, if user inputs 2 then something else happens, if user inputs anything else, than the if statement runs again as only 1 or 2 are valid inputs. However, the problem is that no matter what the user inputs, the if statement does not run, and no error is shown either. I tried a try/except in case an error just isn't showing for some reason (try except ValueError:) and nothing seemed to work I have also tried to specify the input as str, int, float, no specification, raw_input etc. and nothing really works, can someone help?

ps. I am using Visual Studio Code

[As you can see, the if statement does not run as no error is shown even after user input.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJOAW.png)

Comment: What is the class for?

Comment: Because earlier i used a func, all variables I used were local to that function, so I decided to use a class with __init__() but neither did that work, so I just left the class there from earlier, I did not think that would change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the program runs, the class body will be evaluated, meaning the `input("It is now morning, would you like to (1) Leave your house or (2) Do some chores? ")` will prompt for input. That value will then be kept in `first_day_morning.optionone`, however `first_choice`'s `optionone` is different. It is equal to the parameter supplied on the final line, `int(input())`, which will silently prompt for another input, and then convert it to an integer. From what I think you're trying to achieve, I'd recommend you remove the class and change the final line to:

```
first_choice(int(input("It is now morning, would you like to (1) Leave your house or (2) Do some chores? ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_choice():
    print('')
    print("You have chosen to get out of the house for once")

def second_choice():
    print('')
    print("DO LATER")

def third_choice():
    print('')
    print("please choose a valid option")


while True:

    print("""Select a choice""")

    c = int(input('enter your choice:'))
    if c == 1:
        first_choice()
    elif c == 2:
        second_choice()
    elif c == 3:
        third_choice()
    elif c == 4:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont really understand what u r trying to acomplish here, but the code works for me, some tips from a beginer:
-you define optiontwo and never use it
-you you are filling optionone with input inside a class, dont know why, cause is never used
not sure what do u want, but try this:

```
import time

def first_choice(optionone):        #NOT WORKING DOING ELSE COMMAND FOR 1 INPUT
    if optionone == 1: 
        time.sleep(1)
        print('')
        print("You have chosen to get out of the house for once")
    elif optionone == 2: 
        time.sleep(1)
        print('')
        print("DO LATER")
    else: 
        time.sleep(1)
        print('')
        print("please choose a valid option")

first_choice(int(input("It is now morning, would you like to (1) Leave your house or (2) Do some chores? ")))
```

although, test it in console, not sure about vscode but running inside sublime does not ask for input

Comment: I use optiontwo later in the code, not right now, and thank you, I will try in console.